# ClearCase lshist shows too little history - how to see really all of it?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I'm exploring an old ClearCase (UCM) repository (trying to migrate to git, but that's rather not important here). I found a case (or rather many cases) of a file, for which I cannot see history past some point. When I use `cleartool lshist` (or browse versions in a Rational GUI tool for CC), the history of the file appears to start (as version 0 or 1) in a separate development stream, and then later gets delivered into main stream (again as version 0 or 1 in this stream). But from independent sources, as well as from "baseline release streams", I *know* that a file **was present in this path since much, much earlier** (some year or two earlier).

- What could be the reason why this happens?
- How can I see the *full* history of the file, starting from the point in time when it was really first created (or some "other" file in the same exact path)?

Answer (score 0):

It can depends on how the events have been scrubbed from the vob: see "[About ClearCase event records in the VOB database](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21239928)".

I know I lost some events when [raising the VOB family level](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/c_raising_vob_fam_feat_lvls.htm) during ClearCase upgrades.

It can also depends on how the branches and UCM streams have been managed: they could have been obsoleted, or in some case even deleted.

In case of "obsolete", check the filter of a `cleartool lsvtree -graph` window: you can ask to see *all* versions, including ones associated to obsolete streams.